# Onclick reload page with active onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I making multilang index page and i want when i click my language links(AZ, EN, RU) page reload with onclick functions(translateTo("AZ"); under1(); return false;) which have each links. Also i want using pure javascript in codes.
***here is my codes;***

```js
var voc = [
            {
              "AZ":"Log in2",
              "EN":"Log in",
              "RU":"Log in3"
            }
          ];


function translate(ele,lng){
 for(var i=0;i<voc.length;i++){
  for(var k in voc[i]){
   if(voc[i][k] == ele.innerText.trim()){
    ele.innerText = voc[i][lng];
    break;
   }
  }
 }
}
function translateTo(lng){
var trc = document.getElementsByClassName("trans");
for(var i=0;i<trc.length;i++){
translate(trc[i],lng);
}
}
//add this function to any event button.click,select.change or on load
//translateTo("AR");

function under1(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[0].style = "text-decoration:underline;";
  document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[1].style = "text-decoration:none";
  document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[2].style = "text-decoration:none";
}

function under2(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[0].style = "text-decoration:none;";
  document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[1].style = "text-decoration:underline";
  document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[2].style = "text-decoration:none";
}

function under3(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[0].style = "text-decoration:none;";
  document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[1].style = "text-decoration:none";
  document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[2].style = "text-decoration:underline";
}
```

```css
.langselect a{
text-decoration:none;
}

.langselect a:nth-child(2){
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<p>
<span class='trans'>Log in</span> 
</p>

<p class="langselect">
<a href="" class="lang" onclick='translateTo("AZ"); under1(); return false;'>AZ</a>
<a href="" class="lang" onclick='translateTo("EN"); under2(); return false;'>EN</a>
<a href="" class="lang" onclick='translateTo("RU"); under3(); return false;'>RU</a>
</p>
```

Comment: up for uping post.

Comment: What's your issue?

Comment: i just want caching onclick function page reload.